# Detect Installed Software Using Wix

Tags: wix, upgrade, votive, version-detection

Just to start I'm fairly new to wix. I am currently using version 3.0 with the Votive Visual Studio plug in.

I know the upgrade code of an existing software package. I need to be able to detect the installation of this existing program using the particular upgrade code and halt the installation if the version of this program (the one I am trying to detect) is equal to or less than 1.3.0.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Populate the UpgradeTable with the versions you want to detect for and assign it to a property:

```
<Upgrade Id="[the upgrade code]">
   <UpgradeVersion Minimum="0.0.0.0" Maximum="1.3.0.0" OnlyDetect="yes" Property="FOUND">
</Upgrade>
```

Then use the property in the Launch Condition:

```
<Condition Message="Version blah found">FOUND = ""</Condition>
```

For more details:

http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.com/2009/01/launchconditions-findrelatedproducts.html

Comment: Can you give a link where in more such things about wix can be found out ?

Comment: @Ravisha check out "The Definitive Guide to Windows Installer" http://www.amazon.com/Definitive-Guide-Windows-Installer-Experts/dp/1590592972